Is Subject Alternate Name (SAN) became manadatory while using requests in Python
On a private network, I try to access a server with a self-signed certificate I get the following error:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='xxx.yyy.zz', port=32454): Max retries exceeded with url: /south/log-reports?clientAddress=68c038a4... (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, "[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: Hostname mismatch, certificate is not valid for 'xxx.yyy.zz'. (_ssl.c:1007)")))

I'm trying to understand why my mTLS connection to the server is refused using requests in python. 
When I run tests with openssl, curl and via the ssl lib in python it works.
my application runs Python 3.10.14  using: 
requests : 2.31.0 
urllib3 : 2.2.2 
OpenSSL : OpenSSL 3.1.7 3 Sep 2024
This is how my requests.Session object is initialised.
    self.cms_cert = "~/cert/ca/cacert.pem"
    
    # Session for HTTP persistent connection
    self.session = requests.Session()
    self.host = host
    self.timeout = timeout
    self.connection_restored = connection_restored

    self.api_status = ApiClientStatus()
    self.api_status.set_connection_restored(self.connection_restored)


    cms_cert_normalized = str(cms_cert).strip().upper()
    if cms_cert_normalized == 'FALSE':
      adapter = CustomAdapter()
      self.session.mount("https://", adapter)
      self.session.verify = False
    elif cms_cert_normalized == 'TRUE':
      self.session.verify = True
    else:
      self.session.verify = cms_cert

    if gateway_cert:
      self.session.cert = gateway_cert

The certificate does not contain any Subject Alternative Name (SAN).
I wonder if this famous SAN has not become mandatory.

Yes, SAN is required.  See this post: https://serverfault.com/a/915455
